# Cannot use "garden" in terminal on MacOS

Tags: python, bash, macos, kivy

Have been trying to install matplotlib with garden since that's the only way to use it with kivy (if I'm wrong on this I would love to know how to get it to work without). Every time I try to use the "garden" command in the terminal, such as:

```
garden install matplotlib
```

it returns:

```
zsh: command not found: garden
```

I tried basic permission trouble shooting to no avail. Uninstalling and reinstalling garden over and over. Installing it via legacy. Nothing seems to work and at 2:30 hours of trouble shooting I'm at my breaking point. I am in dire need for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I googled for "garden matplotlib" and found [this](https://kraisnet.de/index.php/en/topics/14-visualize-data-with-kivy/46-install-kivy-garden-matplotlib) as the first result. Have you run `pip install kivy-garden`? (If you're using a virtualenv, and you should, within that virtualenv.)

Comment: _How_ you're "uninstalling and reinstalling garden" matters, because the details of how impact _where_ the command gets installed, and thus what needs to be in your PATH to use it. Please make sure you're giving us a [mre] with everything we need to cause the same problem so we can see the issue ourselves.

Comment: (Right now, there's a bug in nixpkgs where the Accelerate framework isn't being passed into Kivy when building on Darwin, but if that was fixed and you had [Nix](https://nixos.org/) installed, the command `nix-shell -p '(python3.withPackages (p: [p.kivy p.matplotlib]))'` would work to give you a Python interpreter with both Kivy and Matplotlib without using Garden).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would that install [this](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib) matplotlib kivy backend (which is what `garden` installs)?

Comment: To answer @CharlesDuffy, what I did was simply `pip install kivy-garden` exactly as you see in every graphing tutorial for kivy, which do as the second step 'garden install matplotlib' which as already mentioned returns the `command not found` or `not enough permission` statements. 
@AKX for virtual environment do you mean a VM, the IDE. the original Terminal from which the `pip` was run or something I do not understand?

Comment: @Zamb_, "virtualenv" has a specific meaning in the Python world -- a virtualenv is basically a directory tree that stores a particular set of Python libraries you can activate and deactivate to install libraries only into that one virtualenv instead of systemwide. See `python -m venv --help`. Once you've activated a virtualenv, `pip` will install packages only for that one venv, and you'll see them only while that same virtualenv remains active; so you can work on different projects that use different, mutually-incompatible sets of libraries within the same computer and OS-level account.

Comment: Is your [PATH](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable) OK?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by locating the "garden" file under the "bin" folder instead of the one found in the `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` which seems to just be a flook. Afterwards I bypassed the need to directly use `garden` in the zsh with the following:

```
python3.10 garden/bin/file/path install matplotlib
```

( I found this work around in the midst of a comment thread on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/ssotuv/no_module_named_garden_main_garden_is_a_package/ )

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.